# Reduce horizontal width of miniframe in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, mini-frames

I have a `beamer` presentation with only three sections. Right now they are spaced at equal distances across the slide, but I would like to compress them so that they are spaced evenly in the left hand side of the headline.

Right now it looks like:

```
Section 1  ---------------------------- Section 2---------------------------Section 3
```

And I would prefer it to look like

```
Section 1-------Section 2-------Section 3
```

Is there a way to customize the horizontal width of the navigation bar at the top? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}\frame{}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Below I'll present two options: the first one is the easier and with sorter code, but depends on you giving the desired total width for the navigation bar; the second one offers you more flexibility and freedom (since you can control the separation between sections at will), but it requires a more involved modification.

1. In this option you redefine the `headline` template, as implemented by the `miniframes` outer theme, so `\insertnavigation` doesn't take the whole `\paperwidth`; for example, using `0.5\paperwidth` (change this value in the line marked with `% Change here` to suit your needs):

   ```
   \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
   \useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}

   \makeatletter
   \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{myminiframes theme}
   {%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
     \end{beamercolorbox}
     \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
       \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vskip2pt % Change here
     \end{beamercolorbox}%
     \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
       \end{beamercolorbox}
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
         leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
         \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
       \end{beamercolorbox}%
     \fi%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
     \end{beamercolorbox}
   }
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}
   \section{Section 1}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \section{Section 2}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \section{Section 3}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \end{document}
   ```

   The resulting headline:

   [image]
2. In this option you need a redefinition of some beamer internals: `\sectionentry` and `\insertnavigation` (original definitions in `beamerbasenavigation.sty`). By changing `\sectionsep` (default of `20pt`) you can have the desired separation between sections in the navigation bar:

   ```
   \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
   \useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}

   \newlength\sectionsep
   \setlength\sectionsep{20pt}% default 1.875ex plus 1fill

   \makeatletter
   \def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
     \ifnum#5=\c@part%
     \beamer@section@set@min@width
     \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip\sectionsep%original: 1.875ex plus 1fill%
     \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
     \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
     \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
     \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#2}%
       \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
       \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
       {%
         \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
         \ifnum\c@section=#1%
           \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
         \else%
           \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
         \fi}%
     }%
     \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
     \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
     \fi\ignorespaces}
   \def\insertnavigation#1{%
     \vbox{{%
       \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
       \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
       \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
       \hbox to #1{\hskip.3cm\setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{\kern1sp}%
         \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
         \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
           \hskip-\sectionsep% original -1.875ex plus 1fill
           \global\beamer@section@min@dim\z@
           \dohead%\hskip\sectionsep%
           \beamer@section@set@min@width
         \box\beamer@sectionbox\hfill\hfill %\hfill%\hskip.3cm
         }%
     }}}  
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}
   \section{Section 1}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \section{Section 2}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \section{Section 3}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \end{document}
   ```

   The resulting headline:

   [image]