# Is it possible to left-align the Beamer "Berlin" theme heading?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

When the "Berlin" LaTex Beamer class is used for presentation sub-sections that have many slides, it happens that the prescribed alignment of the sections in the headline makes some [navigational horizontal dots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85242) either invisible, or they overlap with each other.

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}

\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}

\subsection{AA}

\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}

\section{B}
\subsection{BA}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\subsection{BB}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\subsection{BC}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}

\section{C}
\subsection{CA}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\subsection{CB}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}

\section{D}
\subsection{DA}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\subsection{DB}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

And it generates this result:

[image: Missing horizontal navigational dots for the D subsection of the talk.]

If you take a look at the *upper right corner*, the `D` section seems to be missing some navigational dots. In another configuration, the horizontal navigational dots of the theme may overlap.

Sure, an obvious answer would be to use a fixed smaller number of slides in each section. This is however sometimes not possible.

Is there a way for the sections with their navigational dots to be left-aligned in the headline? There seems to be ample space between them in the image above.

Comment: I am replying via the comment, because the answer I have found is not mine. The **second option** of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228167/24425) is what solves the problem.